# How to register datasource for admin grid layout

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4, di.xml

I am new to magento 2 and my magento version is 2.4. I am trying to show my custom grid on magento admin but, I get the following exception:

```
main.CRITICAL: Exception: Not registered handle faq_question_listing_data_source in /var/www/magento2ce/public/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/CollectionFactory.php:49
Stack trace:
```

What I have done so far is create a menu item called "Frequently Asked Questions" under CONTENT/Elements. Clicking on it redirects me to the page where I want to show my admin grid. I am doing this through ui_components. My grid layout xml looks like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">faq_question_listing.faq_question_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="*/*/new"/>
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true">Add New Question</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <spinner>faq_question_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>faq_question_listing.faq_question_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="faq_question_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</param>
            </storageConfig>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Magento_Cms::page</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="FaqGridDataProvider" name="faq_question_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <templates>
                    <filters>
                        <select>
                            <param name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</param>
                            <param name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</param>
                        </select>
                    </filters>
                </templates>
            </settings>
            <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <captionValue>0</captionValue>
                    <options class="Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options"/>
                    <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                    <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">ns = ${ $.ns }, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete selected items?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="cms/page/massDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="disable">
                <settings>
                    <url path="cms/page/massDisable"/>
                    <type>disable</type>
                    <label translate="true">Disable</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="enable">
                <settings>
                    <url path="cms/page/massEnable"/>
                    <type>enable</type>
                    <label translate="true">Enable</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <settings>
                    <callback>
                        <target>editSelected</target>
                        <provider>faq_question_listing.faq_question_listing.faq_question_columns_editor</provider>
                    </callback>
                    <type>edit</type>
                    <label translate="true">Edit</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="faq_question_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="cms/page/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">faq_question_listing.faq_question_listing.faq_question_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">faq_question_listing.faq_question_listing.cms_page_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>55</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="id">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="Question">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Question</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="Status">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <validation>
                        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    </validation>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="page_layout" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <options class="Magento\Cms\Model\Page\Source\PageLayout"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Layout</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="Status" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="is_active" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <options class="Magento\Cms\Model\Page\Source\IsActive"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="creation_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Created</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="custom_theme_from" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <timezone>false</timezone>
                <dateFormat>MMM d, y</dateFormat>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>date</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Custom design from</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="custom_root_template" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <options class="Magento\Cms\Model\Page\Source\CustomLayout"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Custom Layout</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="meta_title">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Meta Title</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="meta_keywords">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Meta Keywords</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="meta_description">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Meta Description</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PageActions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>id</indexField>
                <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
                <resizeDefaultWidth>107</resizeDefaultWidth>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

My di.xml file is under app\code<Vendor><component>\etc\di.xml and looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Faq\Api\QuestionRepositoryInterface" type="Examples\FirstModule\Model\QuestionRepository" />
    <preference for="Magento\Faq\Api\Data\QuestionInterface" type="Magento\Faq\Model\Question" />
    <preference for="Magento\Faq\Api\Data\QuestionSearchResultsInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults" />

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="magebit_faq_question_listing_data_source"
                      xsi:type="string">Magebit\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Question\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Magebit\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Question\Grid\Collection"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">Magebit_Faq_Question</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">
                Magebit\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Question
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="FaqGridFilterPool"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">
                    Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter
                </item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">
                    Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="FaqGridDataProvider"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">
                Magebit\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Question\Collection
            </argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">
                FaqGridFilterPool
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Magebit\Faq\Indexer\FaqIndexerHandlerVirtual"
                 type="Divante\VsbridgeIndexerCore\Indexer\GenericIndexerHandler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="indexIdentifier" xsi:type="string">vue_storefront_catalog</argument>
            <argument name="typeName" xsi:type="string">faq</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Magebit\Faq\Model\Indexer\Question">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="indexerHandler" xsi:type="object">Magebit\Faq\Indexer\FaqIndexerHandlerVirtual</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

The controller file for this grid layout is under the following dir, app\code<Vendor><component>\Controller\Adminhtml\Question\Index.php and it looks like below:

```
<?php

namespace Magebit\Faq\Controller\Adminhtml\Question;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPagefactory;

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PafeFactory $resultPageFactory
     */

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPagefactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Load the page defined in view\adminhtml\layout\faq_question_index.xml
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\result\Page
     */

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPagefactory->create();
//        $resultPage->setActiveMenu("Magento_Backend::content_elements");
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend('Frequently Asked Questions');
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Now what I do not understand is that, Why am I getting that exception? How do I register my datasource for my grid layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a some mess in your `di.xml` and extra logic.

You can simplify and use Resource Model, you just need to create virtual Grid Collection (Search Result) and define it in CollectionFactory

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->
    <virtualType name="Magebit\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Question\Grid\Collection"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">Magebit_Faq_Question</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magebit\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Question</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="faq_question_listing_data_source"
                      xsi:type="string">Magebit\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Question\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

To be sure that `Magebit_Faq_Question` is correct table name in your DB.

In your `listing` should be

```
    <!-- ... -->
    <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="faq_question_listing_data_source">
    <!-- ... -->
```